# jquery hide and show checkbox event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using plugin to change checkbox template. Now i want to create hide and show in base the of checkbox.

```
$(function($){
    $('body').on('change','[data-type=Working]',function(){
    var Checked = $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0;
    if(Checked){
        $('[data-type=EndDateContainer]').attr('style','display:none;');
    }else{
        $('[data-type=EndDateContainer]').attr('style','display:block;');
    }

});
$('body input[name=Currently]:checked').change();
```

when checkbox is checked given div hide and else show. So plugin changing the template of checkbox and appending some helper things in the template when i check the checkbox its show checks in interface but in html input checkbox not effect this is why my even is not working well.

I'm sharing html

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper">
                                        <span class="icheck-inline"> <div class="icheckbox_md checked"><input data-type="Working" data-md-icheck="" id="1" checked="checked" name="Currently" value="1" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;" data-parsley-multiple="Currently" data-parsley-id="24"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div> <label for="Currently Working" class="inline-label">Currently Working</label></span>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: `$('body input[name=Currently]:checked').change();` is getting executed before event is getting attached

Comment: yes its for edit mode but its doesn't matter i have used it many time